# Using Freeimage api

Tags: c#, asp.net, freeimage

I'm trying to use freeimage to resize iamges and amke sure they're still in cmyk.

however i keep getting stopped at the most basic steps of using freeimage, and i can't find any answers or similar questions about this issue.

i donwloaded the freeimage dll from this site http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html, and tried referencing the dll in the dist folder. This gives me an error saying: "no type libraries found"

i tried referencing the library project to my project, which lets me add "using FreeImageAPI" and the bitmap types, but when i buil my project i get 40 errors along the lines of:

```
"Error  20  Warning as Error: XML comment on 'FreeImageAPI.RGBQUAD.Equals(FreeImageAPI.RGBQUAD)' has a paramref tag for 'obj', but there is no parameter by that name"
```

lastly i tried running the solution in the wrapper folder, to get a look at the samples in there.  but building this solution gives almost 500 errors similar to the one mentioned above.

Am i missing something completely obvious ?

Answer (score 2):

The error has to due with the wrapper library treating warnings as errors. The XML documentation is not fully complete and generates this due to the project settings.

Go to the project options for the Library project (Alt-Enter or Right click -> Properties)
And select "None" under "Treat warnings as errors" as pictured below:

[image: FreeImage project, disabling warnings as errors]

This will allow you to build the project without XML comments causing errors